# date-fns - library Returning date in this format (2018-08-240)

Tags: date, ionic3, date-fns

I have used date-fns Library to format my date.

My code to get today's date is `let today = format(new Date(), 'YYYY-MM-DD');`

But this code returning the date as `2018-08-240`

Why `240` ??

Can anybody help me to get correct date ???
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your behaviour. Do you have a runnable test to share?

Comment: Did you fix the problem ? I have it now ..

Answer (score 0):

The error must have been fixed by now.

Anyway with `date-fns V2+`, the new format to display the date is :

```
 const today = format(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```